# Automating Cloudera Management Services

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am using Cloudera Express. The Cloudera Manager version is 5.12.0. I am trying to automate the bring-up of services like hdfs, hbase... I am able to do so by specifying necessary information of each service in host template, and pushing the host template to Cloudera Manager using curl command which uses Cloudera Manager API. Now, I want to automate the bring-up of Cloudera Management Services like host monitor, service monitor, event server, activity monitor and alert publisher. I have tried to do so by adding the corresponding role types and service types of each service in the host template. When I push the host template to Cloudera Manager using curl command, Cloudera Manager shows an error that It could not find service type 'MGMT' with version CDH 5.12.0. As the management services are different from cluster services like hdfs, yarn, hbase..., How should I automate the bring-up of management services? Is their a dedicated API to automate Management Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the host template only applies to clusters not CM.  To configure CM look at:

- https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/
- https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v17/index.html (in particular the /cm/service/* APIs)

Comment: Oh, yes. You are right. I have a deployment template, which I have changed according to my needs and pushed the template to the end point: cm/deployment. It shows "Request to service monitor failed","Request to Host Monitor failed" in CM. When I checked the instances of the Cloudera management services I have pushed, the status of all the role instances is "stopped". When I start/restart the role instances, there is an error and the role instances are not starting.

Comment: You could try the cm/service/roles/{ROLE}/config endpoint (https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v17/path__cm_service_roles_-roleName-_config.html) first then once you've gotten that working, use that for cm/deployment.